# Is there a way to configure god to restart a watch every x amount of time?

Tags: ruby, twitter, god

I have a little script streaming data from Twitter and feeding it to another application. I am using for that the official `twitter` gem in its 5.0.0.rc.1 release with the streaming feature being flagged as experimental, which is fine with me. It's not a critical application anyway.

In order to have it withstand unforeseen crashes and other networking problems and so, I have this script monitored by `god` (0.13.3) and it works indeed most of the time. For some reason though it appears that occasionally the script will completely hang and sit idly while tweets should be received every odd second (debug setup is using widely used terms).

`ps` lists it as `Ss`, consuming 0% CPU and a mere 25MB of RAM.

I believe there might be some gotchas in the `twitter` gem (or a dependency) and I do not have the leisure to dive into the code now and try to fix it.

```
God.watch do |w|
  w.name = 'twitter-streamer'
  w.env = {
    'TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY' => 'key',
    'TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET' => 'secret',
    'TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN' => 'token',
    'TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET' => 'very_secret'
  }
  w.start = "twitter_streamer --hashtags cheese"
  w.keepalive
  w.log = File.join APP_HOME, 'log', 'twitter-streamer.log'
end
```

This is the definition of my watch. As you can see, it's pretty much by the book. What I would like, is a condition that would allow me to forcefully restart the process every so often. That would is an acceptable workaround for my needs.

Perhaps something like

```
# lifecycle
w.lifecycle do |on|
  on.condition(:every) do |c|         
    c.within = 15.minute
    c.transition = :restart
  end
end
```

This is based off the `:flapping` condition block sample on the project's homepage. Is there a way to achieve this or would I need to implement my own condition?

Comment: Stackoverflow presented this related question, which is indeed - to my understanding - related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041731/rubygem-god-time-limit-configuration-for-process?rq=1 . It kind of follows your workaround idea, iiuc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That seems something I might be able to build upon.